# jQuery ajax requests: Success functions called in sequence of request

Tags: jquery, ajax

We have a jQuery app where some requests for the same URL may take much longer than others. The user fires off ajax posts (by making a change in the UI), these fire off a get request on success that updates the UI. When the earliest of the get requests takes a long time, the later one (which is much quicker) is delayed until the slower one finishes in FF & chrome, but not IE.

POST1  (associated with success1), returns OK quickly
POST2 (associated with success2)
success1 and 2 are the same function

now,
success1 -> GET which takes a long time (we expect this)
success2 -> GET which *should* return quickly (before response to success1)
(both GETs, above, are to the same URL)

what we're seeing:
in IE: success 2 completes quickly, success1 completes later
in chrome and FF: success2 is being held up until success1 completes :-(

We expect success2 to complete before success1.

Any idea why there is the delay in FF and chrome, and what we might do to diagnose/fix this?

Comment: if you need success2 to complete before success1, make the requests in order, a.k.a make the POST2, then when it is done make POST1....

Comment: The POSTs are in response to user input and we don't know before-hand whether the subsequent GET is going to be long or short.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance of providing the precise code, client side, that encounters this problem? I would prefer to analyse your code to determine the problem and fix, rather than invent some of my own which may or may not exhibit the problem. Regards

Comment: thanks for the offer Jim - it's a little complex to recreate since you'd need to have a server-side that also emulates the fact that one ajax call gets a quick response and the other a slow one.  in the end we used http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ajaxq/ to implement a queue of ajax requests that we had more fine-grained control over...